# BeautifulSoup: extract href from anchor tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been reading other people methods but I can't connect the dots here and I need to extract the href: "/agente/listing/details/5828063" from the anchor tag. (2nd line of the code below)

The source page snippet goes as:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 12px auto;">
  <a title="Abrir imóvel numa nova tab" data-bind="attr:{ href: '/agente/listing/details/' + ID }" target="_blank"
    href="/agente/listing/details/5828063">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
  </a>

  <div class="discount-container loaded">

    <div data-bind="if: CampaingDescription"></div>

    <span data-bind="click: $parent.ShowListingDetails, attr:{ id: 'bkmimg' + ID }" style="cursor:pointer"
      id="bkmimg5828063">
      <!-- ko if: ListingPictureUrl != '' && ListingPictureUrl != null -->
      <img class="picture" data-bind="attr:{ src:ListingPictureUrl, 'data-original': ListingPictureUrl}"
        onerror="this.src='/agente/images/default-listing.png'"
        src="https://remaxpt-media.azurewebsites.net/images/listings/12204/122041118-203/L_07e3e17f83064ad2a228f234bf57b32a.jpg?w=160&amp;h=160"
        data-original="https://remaxpt-media.azurewebsites.net/images/listings/12204/122041118-203/L_07e3e17f83064ad2a228f234bf57b32a.jpg?w=160&amp;h=160">
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: ListingPictureUrl == '' || ListingPictureUrl == null -->
      <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <!-- ko if: MLS -->
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `soup.find('a')['href']` ?

Comment: doesn't work. it returns '/agente/' only

Comment: @Rakesh Include also your python code for us to see what the issue is

Comment: @GabrielFerreira The solution suggested by Rakesh does work. You should provide the url or the entire html code. Otherwise you are going to confuse beginners.

Comment: there are too many characters in the html file and the url is useless without my ID and password. I would share them if the site itself had no financial connections but it has.


 link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[title^='Abrir imóvel numa nova tab']").get_attribute('href')

using selenium it works fine but I can't find ALL the links on the page, there are always at least 10. They change the ID, after /details/

Comment: Is the HTML you shared what you see in your browser, or the result of the request in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the attribute of the `a` tag using `get()`

**CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 12px auto;">
  <a title="Abrir imóvel numa nova tab" data-bind="attr:{ href: '/agente/listing/details/' + ID }" target="_blank"
    href="/agente/listing/details/5828063">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
  </a>

  <div class="discount-container loaded">

    <div data-bind="if: CampaingDescription"></div>

    <span data-bind="click: $parent.ShowListingDetails, attr:{ id: 'bkmimg' + ID }" style="cursor:pointer"
      id="bkmimg5828063">
      <!-- ko if: ListingPictureUrl != '' && ListingPictureUrl != null -->
      <img class="picture" data-bind="attr:{ src:ListingPictureUrl, 'data-original': ListingPictureUrl}"
       onerror="this.src='/agente/images/default-listing.png'"
        src="https://remaxpt-media.azurewebsites.net/images/listings/12204/122041118-203/L_07e3e17f83064ad2a228f234bf57b32a.jpg?w=160&amp;h=160"
        data-original="https://remaxpt-media.azurewebsites.net/images/listings/12204/122041118-203/L_07e3e17f83064ad2a228f234bf57b32a.jpg?w=160&amp;h=160">
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: ListingPictureUrl == '' || ListingPictureUrl == null -->
      <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <!-- ko if: MLS -->
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
alink = soup.find('a')
print(alink.get('href'))
```

**RESULT:**

```
/agente/listing/details/5828063
```

Comment: it doesn't work when facing the full page source code, keeps returning the same thing, /agente/

I can't load the full page :') (new to stackoverflow), how should I edit the question so you can see it?

Comment: @GabrielFerreira You can edit your question and add the url of the page you are trying to scrape, or post it in comment

Comment: you would need user id and pw to enter it, I'm developing my own code to help me with my work on my daily basis.

I could send you the .html via something else if you don't mind

Comment: @GabrielFerreira following my snippet, what is the result if you `print(soup)`?

Comment: it prints: /agente/

Comment: I managed to get the href using selenium, by driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[title^='Abrir imóvel numa nova tab']").get_attribute('href')

now the problem is that by using this, I only get the 1st href, the one of the first item on the list and I needed all of the list item's hrefs

Comment: @GabrielFerreira https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html there's difference between **find_element** and **find_element(s)**

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Thank you! Now its time for me to finish the project and hide in shame because clearly, I haven't read the whole documentation...

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 12px auto;">
  <a title="Abrir imóvel numa nova tab" data-bind="attr:{ href: '/agente/listing/details/' + ID }" target="_blank"
    href="/agente/listing/details/5828063">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
  </a>

  <div class="discount-container loaded">

    <div data-bind="if: CampaingDescription"></div>

    <span data-bind="click: $parent.ShowListingDetails, attr:{ id: 'bkmimg' + ID }" style="cursor:pointer"
      id="bkmimg5828063">
      <!-- ko if: ListingPictureUrl != '' && ListingPictureUrl != null -->
      <img class="picture" data-bind="attr:{ src:ListingPictureUrl, 'data-original': ListingPictureUrl}"
        onerror="this.src='/agente/images/default-listing.png'"
        src="https://remaxpt-media.azurewebsites.net/images/listings/12204/122041118-203/L_07e3e17f83064ad2a228f234bf57b32a.jpg?w=160&amp;h=160"
        data-original="https://remaxpt-media.azurewebsites.net/images/listings/12204/122041118-203/L_07e3e17f83064ad2a228f234bf57b32a.jpg?w=160&amp;h=160">
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: ListingPictureUrl == '' || ListingPictureUrl == null -->
      <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <!-- ko if: MLS -->
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

target = soup.find("a", {'title': 'Abrir imóvel numa nova tab'}).get("href")
print(target)
```

Output:

```
/agente/listing/details/5828063
```